# How do I submit this form without page reload?

Tags: javascript

So basically I have this interest slider plugin that calculates the repayments on a loan over a certain period of time - https://loancalc.000webhostapp.com/

But the problem I am having is submitting the form without reloading the page, currently you enter your name and email.

I have included this ajax script on line 1146 of slider.js but the slider continues to reload the page when submitting the form.

I am told it could be because i'm not enqueuing the script (for wordpress) properly.

```
jQuery('.qis-register').on('submit', 'input', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = $("input#yourname").val();
    var email = $("input#youremail").val();
    if (name == ""){
        $("input#yourname").focus;
        return false;
    }

    else if (email == ""){
        $("input#youremail").focus;
        return false;
    }
    else{
        jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "quick-interest-slider.php",
           data: {
                name:name,
                email:email,
                qissubmit:$(".qissubmit").val(),
                qisapply:$(".qisapply").val(),
                part2submit:$(".part2submit").val(),
     },
           done: function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
        }
    });
}});
```

The full code is here (slider.js, quick-interest-slider.php, register.php) - https://github.com/Curnow93/quick-interest-slider/tree/master/quick-interest-slider

Comment: you're adding code to a submit event while asking how to do this without submitting... the logic error should be clear.

Comment: This code should throw an error about `event` being undefined. As for the event, you'll want to handle either a `click` on the button or `submit` of the form. Then simply `return false;` from the event handler to tell the browser that the event is handled.

Comment: @Steven Stark I want to submit the page without reload not "submit the page without submitting"

Comment: then include your complete code. I assume your form tag has a target on it. this will reload your page.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `submit` event on the `input`. It should be on the form. Also, you need to pass the `event` to the callback function.

```
jQuery('.qis_form').on('submit', function(event) {
```

Also your selector doesn't select anything. I have updated it using the right selector.

Comment: I have tried this but it continue to reload the page.

Comment: @StevenCurnow We need a [mcve] that has the problem. Can you make one, please?